# Filter array, obtaining a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
["q1":[{"key_api":86,"question_api":"q1","answer_api":"a1"},{"key_api":87,"question_api":"q1","answer_api":"a2"},{"key_api":88,"question_api":"q1","answer_api":"a3"},{"key_api":89,"question_api":"q1","answer_api":"a4"}],
"q2":[{"key_api":90,"question_api":"q2","answer_api":"a5"},{"key_api":91,"question_api":"q2","answer_api":"a7"}{"key_api":92,"question_api":"q2","answer_api":"a9"}],
"q3":[{"key_api":93,"question_api":"q3","answer_api":"a1"},{"key_api":94,"question_api":"q3","answer_api":"a2"},{"key_api":95,"question_api":"q3","answer_api":"a3"},{"key_api":96,"question_api":"q3","answer_api":"a4"}],
"q4":[{"key_api":97,"question_api":"q4","answer_api":"a10"},{"key_api":98,"question_api":"q4","answer_api":"a11"},{"key_api":99,"question_api":"q4","answer_api":"a12"},{"key_api":100,"question_api":"q4","answer_api":"a13"}]]
```

Also, I have this string:

```
"q4"
```

I'd like to filter the array, obtaining this list (in practice, the possible answers for the third question):

```
["a10", "a11", "a12", "a13"]
```

I prefer native js, if possible (but if it involves a lot of code I can consider libraries).
I'm using js for one week now: operations like this one feel natural in Python but here I'm in trouble.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: your data is not valid. arrays have no properties in literal notation. btw, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the initial JSON you provided is actually meant to be an object consisting of properties that are arrays (because JSON arrays cannot have properties), you would simply use `Array.prototype.map` on one of the object's properties:

```js
   const dataObject = {
"q1": [{ "key_api": 86, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a1" }, { "key_api": 87, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a2" }, { "key_api": 88, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a3" }, { "key_api": 89, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a4" }],
"q2": [{ "key_api": 90, "question_api": "q2", "answer_api": "a5" }, { "key_api": 91, "question_api": "q2", "answer_api": "a7" }, { "key_api": 92, "question_api": "q2", "answer_api": "a9" }],
"q3": [{ "key_api": 93, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a1" }, { "key_api": 94, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a2" }, { "key_api": 95, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a3" }, { "key_api": 96, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a4" }],
"q4": [{ "key_api": 97, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a10" }, { "key_api": 98, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a11" }, { "key_api": 99, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a12" }, { "key_api": 100, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a13" }]
};
console.log(dataObject['q4'].map(item => item.answer_api));
```

If you want to do this for all of the entries/keys in the object, you can combine this with `Object.keys` by iterating over the return value, like so:

```js
const dataObject = {
    "q1": [{ "key_api": 86, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a1" }, { "key_api": 87, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a2" }, { "key_api": 88, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a3" }, { "key_api": 89, "question_api": "q1", "answer_api": "a4" }],
    "q2": [{ "key_api": 90, "question_api": "q2", "answer_api": "a5" }, { "key_api": 91, "question_api": "q2", "answer_api": "a7" }, { "key_api": 92, "question_api": "q2", "answer_api": "a9" }],
    "q3": [{ "key_api": 93, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a1" }, { "key_api": 94, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a2" }, { "key_api": 95, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a3" }, { "key_api": 96, "question_api": "q3", "answer_api": "a4" }],
    "q4": [{ "key_api": 97, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a10" }, { "key_api": 98, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a11" }, { "key_api": 99, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a12" }, { "key_api": 100, "question_api": "q4", "answer_api": "a13" }]
};
Object.keys(dataObject).forEach(key => {
    console.log(dataObject[key].map(item => item.answer_api));
})
```

Comment: btw, the question does **not** contain any [JSON](https://json.org/), which is a string.

Comment: @NinaScholz okay, very helpful. Thanks.